# bashscript to go through huge file and remove some lines

Tags: bash

I have a large(1TB) text file that I need to go through and remove lines that contains "drop table..."
and then dump the result to a new file.
how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` searches for substrings in a text file, and the `-v` matches lines that don't have the substring:

```
grep -v "drop table" outfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: The core unix utils have been honed over years of development to handle even (especially?) large files like this very well.